# Celsius to fahrenheit calculator console application C#

Tags: c#, visual-c#-express-2010

I have written this code for my Celsius to Fahrenheit and vice versa converter.
everything seems to be working fine. the only thing that is not going well is that when the user gets an converted temperature the text colour should change depending on the temperature.
I will also post my code underneath and can anyone tell me if i have done anything wrong and what I have to do to fix it 
Thank you I really appreciate it

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        // Program that converts Celsius to Fahrenheit and vice versa


        int Celsius, Fahrenheit, UserChoice;

        //Console background colour
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkMagenta;
        Console.Clear();

        Console.SetCursorPosition(15, 0);
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the eBSolutions Temperature Converter By Y. Ibrahim");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("<<<<<<<<<<<< Press Enter to continue to the Main Menu >>>>>>>>>>>>");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();


        Console.SetCursorPosition(15, 0);
        Console.WriteLine("Main Menu");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 4);
        Console.WriteLine("1) Convert Celsius to Fahrenheit");
        Console.WriteLine("2) Convert Fahrenheit to Celsius");
        Console.WriteLine("3) Exit ");
        Console.WriteLine("4) Help ");



        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 9);
        Console.WriteLine("Please Enter one of the provided options from above");
        UserChoice = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Clear();


        // Convert Celsius to Fahrenheit.
        if (UserChoice == 1)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(20, 0);
            Console.WriteLine("Converting Celsius To Fahrenheit");

            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 4);
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the Temperature in Celsius(°C) : ");
            Celsius = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Fahrenheit = (Celsius * 9) / 5 + 32;
            Console.WriteLine("The temperature in Fahrenheit is(°F) : " + Fahrenheit);


            if (Fahrenheit <= -50)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;

            }
            if (Fahrenheit <= -10)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
            }
            if (Fahrenheit == 0)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            }
            if (Fahrenheit >= 10)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            }
            if (Fahrenheit >= 50)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;

                Console.ReadLine();



            }


            // Convert Fahrenheit to Celsius.

            if (UserChoice == 2)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(20, 0);
                Console.WriteLine("Converting Fahrenheit To Celsius");

                Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 4);
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the Temperature in Fahrenheit(°F) : ");
                Fahrenheit = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Celsius = (Fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9;
                Console.WriteLine("The temperature in Celsius is(°C) : " + Celsius);

                if (Celsius <= -50)
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                }
                if (Celsius <= -10)
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                }
                if (Celsius == 0)
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                }
                if (Celsius >= 10)
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                }
                if (Celsius >= 50)
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;

                    Console.ReadLine();


                    //Exit

                    if (UserChoice != 3)
                    {

                        Console.ReadLine();

                        //Help Facility

                        if (UserChoice == 4)
                        {
                            Console.SetCursorPosition(20, 0);
                            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Temperature Calculator Help Facility");
                            Console.WriteLine("");

                            Console.ReadLine();
                        }


                        {




                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: try setting the color before you output the text

Answer (score 1):

You need to change order of your logic. You are writing string to Console before you are changing ForegroundColor. Move this if's (checking for temperature)

```
if (Fahrenheit <= -50)
{
     Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;

}
```

before:

```
Console.WriteLine("The temperature in Fahrenheit is(°F) : " + Fahrenheit);
```

Your code is changing color after writing to console. Changing it before will affect color of printed text.

Also use `if else` instead of multiple `if's`.

So it should look like:

1. Get value from input
2. Convert
3. Set color depending on converted value
4. Print output

You should also extract your if's to some private method. You have duplicated code.

Comment: @Yasser is it working fine now? Do you need any more assistance?